# Can't get Craft cms/server running on Heroku

Tags: heroku, server, content-management-system

I'm familiar with heroku, but new to Craft cms. In order to get a site running, I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@aj1215/craft-cms-on-heroku-79b991665b0b#.8b561b1b4

But the site isn't functioning. My heroku app just results in: “Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.”

My development server runs fine. But I have no idea what I need to do to get the heroku app to function. I'm pulling my hair out.

I've tried everything I can think of, but can't get it to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

These are messages toward the end of my heroku logs:

> 2016–01–31T03:09:21.480751+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] “server”
>   directive is not allowed here in /app/nginx_app.conf:1 
>   2016–01–31T03:09:21.475721+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx… 
>   2016–01–31T03:09:21.481090+00:00 app[web.1]: Process exited
>   unexpectedly: nginx  2016–01–31T03:09:21.481236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   Going down, terminating child processes… 
>   2016–01–31T03:09:22.183035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1  2016–01–31T03:09:22.182791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed  2016–01–31T03:09:27.185620+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc=”App crashed” method=GET
>   path=”/” host=paradata2.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=1e502143–94ac-4aea-b34b-3087addd1d20 fwd=”172.11.56.78"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

**nginx_app.conf file:**

```
    server {
    http {
        location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }
        location @rewriteapp {
            # rewrite all to index.php
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
        }
        location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
            client_max_body_size 20M;
            fastcgi_pass heroku-fcgi;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: message must be format as quote an not as source code, this improve the way to identify them and separate source code of the rest of the context

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue.

I needed to remove calls to 'server' and 'http' in my enginx_app.conf file. Now the file only makes calls to 'location'.